# Prevent useEffect until page and api completely loaded

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

```
const page = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const {data, isLoading} = useGetUser();
  
  useEffect() => ({
    if (isLoading) return;
    if (!data) {
      router.push('/create-account');
    }
  }, [isLoading, data])
  
   if (isLoading) {
    return <spinner />
   }
   
   return (
    <Home />
   )
}
```

I need to redirect to the `create-account` page if a user is not authenticated.
The above code works well. But it redirects to `create-account` page when I navigate the home page after signing in.
I debugged and I found the `isLoading` and `data` will be `false` together when the page is loading the first time.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: The identifier `loading` does not seem to be defined anywhere in the code. How can the if statements be evaluated if `loading` is not defined? Shouldn't it be `if (isLoading) { ... }` ?

Comment: @Joel Edited to `isLoading`

Comment: What kind of data type is `data`? If it's an array you could probably check it's length. If length is 0 then redirect. If it an object then you could probably check if an attribute exists or not.

Comment: "I found the isLoading and data will be false together when the page is loading the first time." there seems to be the bug that you need to fix. what does `useGetUser` look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect() => ({
    if (!loading){
       if (!data) {
         router.push('/create-account');
       }
    }
  }, [loading, data]) // on loading completed
```

This will resolve your issue

Comment: How is this logically different from OPs code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `useLayoutEffect` hook? This hooks runs before the page is painted.